# Check path to imported module without __file__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm importing a module from a certain program, from within the program itself.
I can run Python command, and I need the path to the python module that I'm importing.
The module contains no `__file__` property, which seems to be the main way.

Using `sys.modules[<module>]` returns `<module (built-in)>`

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you explain your case with an example?

Comment: There is no example because I was using a program which has built-in modules inaccessible from outside the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `getfile()` method provided by **[`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)**.

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(inspect) # returns '/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc'
```